# How can you get a location in android when all location providers are disabled?

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

LocationManager has a method, getlastknownlocation. From the documentation this method: "Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider. **This can be done without starting the provider**"

However this method only returns a location if the provider is currently enabled.

I'm a little confused by this, if this method can get a cached location without starting the provider, why would it only return a location if the provider is *currently* enabled?

How can I guarantee a location, however inaccurate and outdated it may be, even if all providers are disabled?

Comment: For privacy purpose android will not give even cached location, until user explicitly tells it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If the user hasn't got any location providers enabled, you can't deliver a location. If the user hasn't enabled GPS and the user has no Internet connection, you can't get a network-based location (network-based location requires assistance from the server).

Sometimes you just can't tell the user where he is (or was).

Comment: Well, you could simply manually cache a location from when things were enabled.

Comment: Well, perhaps you could. But the security model of the Android OS says that if the user doesn't want to enable locations, the application can't have them. This isn't completely a technical problem, it is partly a user privacy/security-policy problem.